# Are we able to generate fusion by firing macroscopic particles really fast?

Tags: science-based, science-fiction, warfare, weapons, nuclear-weapons

Big gun in space (let's not care about how the gun will work yet)
Pew pew,

If we fire fusion fuel,
Would we be able to cause a fusion reaction upon the particle's impact?
What speed would that take?

Comment: We are actually creating a fusion by shooting two plasmas at each other and then "heating them up", no idea about just shooting something hot enough or composite to simply cause it in normal conditions. Maybe this will be at least little helpful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_bDXXWQxK38 [A New Way to Achieve Nuclear Fusion: Helion by Real Engineering]

Answer (score 3):

Another name for this is Macrons or "Dust Gun".

(politics is making googling particularly frustrating,but here is a good video.)

[The Deadliest Hard Sci-Fi Weapon You've Never Heard Of (Macrons, Dust Guns)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MPVhOy3mWQQ)

At the highest end of the possibilities the "dust" is delivered at such speeds with fisionable payloads, causing billions of small fission/fusion explosions upon impact. One of the few sci-fi weapons that can actually exceede the required energy to produce and deliver energy.

Comment: And here's a good article with real math: https://toughsf.blogspot.com/2019/11/hypervelocity-macron-accelerators.html

Comment: For anyone unwilling to do the deep dive, the impact velocity to ignite Deuterium-Tritium is roughly 1000 km/s, though special shaped impactors can probably bring this down to 100 km/s. Note that this technology enables The Expanse style torch drives as well.

Answer (score 2):

That something doing routinely in particle accelerators by, among others, teams trying to [synthesize transuranic elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic_element)

> A synthetic element is one of 24 known chemical elements that do not occur naturally on Earth: they have been created by human manipulation of fundamental particles in a nuclear reactor, a particle accelerator, or the explosion of an atomic bomb; thus, they are called "synthetic", "artificial", or "man-made".
>
> The first entirely synthetic element to be made was curium, synthesized in 1944 by Glenn T. Seaborg, Ralph A. James, and Albert Ghiorso by bombarding plutonium with alpha particles.

Comment: The D-T fusion cross-section peaks around 100 keV, which is easy with almost any ion accelerator.

Answer (score 0):

[Helion](https://invidious.namazso.eu/watch?v=_bDXXWQxK38), a fusion research company, takes this approach already. They have two highly-charged toroids of fusion fuel and fire them at each other. When they collide, the collision does exactly what you ask about: the energy of the impact causes fusion.

Two caveats:

- The toroids they fire are already highly charged plasma. The energy of the collision gives them that extra push over the cliff. It wouldn't work with cold stuff.
- They are not 'macroscopic objects' like footballs; they are macroscopic clouds of microscopic particles. The toroids themselves are macroscopic.

---

Now if the 'big gun in space' is a plasma gun (a common trope), then all this fits together nicely and the answer is definitely yes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, totally.
Accelerating particles was actually how the first fusion experiments on earth were done.
However you will need to be FAST. With fast meaning a substantial fraction of the speed of light, because you will need to overcome the Coulomb barrier.
There is [a similar question here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/393947/minimum-speed-of-a-baseball-to-cause-nuclear-fusion-in-air) where you see can how to calculate it. It will not really be a great energy source tho...